# Kafka Streams Health Indicator with a restoring state store

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

The default setup with kafka-streams and spring-boot-actuator includes adding the state of the stream threads into the health check endpoint. This is great, but if my application is using a state store, and that store is still in the process of restoring, the application still returns as being Up. When I then try and interact with the store I get one of the following errors about the stream thread not being running

`Cannot get state store <storename> because the stream thread is STARTING, not RUNNING`
`Cannot get state store <storename> because the stream thread is PARTITIONS_ASSIGNED, not RUNNING`

Is there any way I can include this stream thread status in the health checks, so that I can prevent requested being routed to it until the state store is available again?